# Collect data to object with four async calls and handle the object onready

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery-deferred

I have a handler (callback), an object to handle and four functions, which collect the data to object. In my case I wish to asynchronously call four data retrievers and when execution of all four is complete, handle the resulting object (something similar to the following):

```
var data = {};

function handle (jsObj) {}

// data retrieving
function getColorData () {}
function getSizeData () {}
function getWeightData () {}
function getExtraData () {}

data.color = getColorData();
data.size = getSizeData();
data.weight = getWeightData();
data.extra = getExtraData();

handle( data );
```

Of course, this code will not work properly. And if I chain data retrieving functions, they will be called one after another, right?
All four functions should be called asynchronously, cause they are being executed for too long to call them one by one.

**Updated:**

Thanks to everybody for your suggestions! I prefered `$.Deferred()`, but I found it slightly difficult to make it work the way I need. What I need is to asynchronously make a `view`, which requires four kinds of data (`extraData`, `colorData`, `sizeData` & `weightData`) and I have three objects: `App`, `Utils` & `Tools`.

Just a small description: `view` is created by calling `App.getStuff` passed `App.handleStuff` as a callback. Callback in the body of `App.getStuff` is called only `$.when(App.getExtraData(), App.getColorData(), App.getSizeData(), App.getWeightData())`. Before that `Utils.asyncRequest` passed `Tools.parseResponse` as a callback is called.

So, now the question is should I create four deferred objects inside each `App.get*Data()` and also `return deferred.promise()` from each of them?
And should I `deferred.resolve()` in the last function in my order (`Tools.parseResponse` for `App.getExtraData` in my example)?

```
var view,
    App,
    Utils = {},
    Tools = {};

// Utils
Utils.asyncRequest = function (path, callback) {
    var data,
        parseResponse = callback;

    // do something with 'data'

    parseResponse( data );
};

// Tools
Tools.parseResponse = function (data) {
    var output = {};

    // do something to make 'output' from 'data'

    /* So, should the deferred.resolve() be done here? */
    deferred.resolve(output);
    /// OR   deferred.resolve();
    /// OR   return output;
};

// App
App = {
    // Only one method really works in my example
    getExtraData : function () {
        var deferred = new jQuery.Deferred();

        Utils.asyncRequest("/dir/data.txt", Tools.parseResponse);

        return deferred.promise();
    },
    // Others do nothing
    getColorData  : function () { /* ... */ },
    getSizeData   : function () { /* ... */ },
    getWeightData : function () { /* ... */ }
};
App.getStuff = function (callback) {
    $.when( 
        App.getExtraData(), 
        App.getColorData(), 
        App.getSizeData(), 
        App.getWeightData()
    )
     .then(function (extraData, colorData, sizeData, weightData) {
        var context,
            handleStuff = callback;

        // do something to make all kinds of data become a single object

        handleStuff( context );
    });
};
App.handleStuff = function (stuff) { /* ... */ };

/// RUN
view = App.getStuff( App.handleStuff );
```

I did not expect the code in my example above to work, it is for illustrative purposes.

I've been trying to solve this for quiet a long time and it still gives no result. The documentation for `jQuery.Deferred()` and discussions around this, unfortunately, did not help me. So, I would be very glad and greatful for any help or advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are [Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) / Deferreds.

With promises you can write something like:

```
when(getColorData(), getSizeData(), getWeightData(), getExtraData()).then(
    function (colorData, sizeData, weightData, extraData) {
        handle(/*..*/);
    }
)
```

The `get*Data()` functions will return a promise that they fulfill when their assynchronous call is complete.

Ex:

```
function getData() {
    var promise = new Promise();
    doAjax("getData", { "foo": "bar" }, function (result) {
        promise.resolve(result);
    });
    return promise;
}
```

The `when` simply counts the number arguments, if all it's promises are resolved, it will call `then` with the results from the promises.

jQuery has an OK implementation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you would use a counter that gets incremented as each asynchronous call completes. The main caller should proceed after the counter has been incremented by all the asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 0):

What I could suggest for this scenario would be something like that. 
write a function like this

```
var completed = 0;
checkHandler = function() {
  if(completed == 4) {
    handle(data);
  }
}
```

where completed is the number of positive callbacks you must receive. 
As soon as every function receives a callback you can increment the "completed" counter and invoke the checkHandler function. and you're done!

in example

```
function getColorData() {
   $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
      completed++;
      checkHandler();
   });
}
```